# What is the relationship between monad functions dist and join in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

I was doing one of the homeworks from functional programming course and found some problems understanding monads in Haskell.

So, we were given a type:

```
data Annotated e a = a :# e
infix 0 :#
```

The task was to implement some functions with given type signatures, which I did. They pass needed tests (separately):

```
mapAnnotated :: (a -> b) -> (Annotated e a -> Annotated e b)
mapAnnotated f (x :# w) = f x :# w

joinAnnotated :: Semigroup e => Annotated e (Annotated e a) -> Annotated e a
joinAnnotated ((b :# m) :# n) = b :# m <> n

distAnnotated :: Semigroup e => (Annotated e a, Annotated e b) -> Annotated e (a, b)
distAnnotated (x :# m, y :# n) = (x, y) :# m <> n
```

However, we were also asked to satisfy following equation:

```
distAnnotated (p, q) = joinAnnotated (mapAnnotated (\a -> mapAnnotated (\b -> (a, b)) q) p)
```

I can't quite get my head around so many function applications, so for other types with similar tasks I just did what seemed "natural" and it worked, but here it doesn't and I can't see why, since I don't even see other ways to implement these functions. What am I missing?

Comment: What justifies the connective "however"? One thing that could justify it would be finding values of `p` and `q` for which the equation is not satisfied. Have you? Do you have another reason that you think your implementations and the requested law are in conflict?

Comment: The reason I think my implementation is incorrect is that we have tests which, well, test this equation (and basic correctness as well) and they fail.
I would readily provide examples where the equation doesn't hold, but that would mean my understanding of it (and also the solution, I guess), which is precisely the problem =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the troublesome equation and systematically substitute the definitions, working it inside-out:

```
-- Given
mapAnnotated f (x :# w) = f x :# w
joinAnnotated ((b :# m) :# n) = b :# m <> n
distAnnotated (x :# m, y :# n) = (x, y) :# m <> n
p = x :# m
q = y :# n

-- Goal
distAnnotated (p, q) = joinAnnotated (mapAnnotated (\a -> mapAnnotated (\b -> (a, b)) q) p)

-- Right-hand side
joinAnnotated (mapAnnotated (\a -> mapAnnotated (\b -> (a, b)) q) p)
joinAnnotated (mapAnnotated (\a -> mapAnnotated (\b -> (a, b)) (y :# n)) (x :# m))
joinAnnotated (mapAnnotated (\a -> (\b -> (a, b)) y :# n) (x :# m))
joinAnnotated (mapAnnotated (\a -> (a, y) :# n) (x :# m))
joinAnnotated (mapAnnotated (\a -> (a, y) :# n) (x :# m))
joinAnnotated ((\a -> (a, y) :# n) x :# m)
joinAnnotated (((x, y) :# n) :# m)
(x, y) :# n <> m
-- Left-hand side
distAnnotated (p, q)
distAnnotated (x :# m, y :# n)
(x, y) :# m <> n
-- LHS /= RHS
```

The problem, therefore, is that `distAnnotated` combines the annotations in a different order than `joinAnnotated` (`m <> n` versus `n <> m`). The usual way to make them agree is changing `joinAnnotated` so that the outside annotation comes first:

```
joinAnnotated ((b :# m) :# n) = b :# n <> m
```

This fits both the natural sequencing of computations in the monadic bind (`m >>= f = joinAnnotated (mapAnnotated f m)`) and the conventional left-to-right order of applicative effects (`p <*> q = ap p q = mapAnnotated (\(f, a) -> f a) (distAnnotated (p, q))`).